# Installing cookiejar library in Rstudio

Tags: r

I had been using the following method to import and use the cookiejar library in R studio for quite a while and it just stopped working as it used to.

More specifically I have a zipped file with the name "cookiejar_0.1.0.tar.gz" and I follow the next steps to import it in R.

```
install.packages("C:/Users/sample/sample/sample/sample/cookiejar_0.1.0.tar.gz",repos=NULL, type="source")
library(cookiejar)
```

And all of a sudden it gives me the following error which I was not able to find something significant on the web.

Error:

```
Error in library(cookiejar) : there is no package called 'cookiejar'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval -> library
Execution halted
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does `list.files("C:/Users/sample/sample/sample/sample/")` return?

Comment: @IRTFM it returns: "character (0)" in the console. So that .gz file that I am specifying it can be indeed found with that path. I am really baffled to be honest. Nothing has changed on my end, the version of R, Rstudio or anything else.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any files in that directory. You need to figure out where you put it.

Comment: @IRTFM Apparently something went out of place and a different directory was set with similar name (I know it's a very bad practice not to have distinguished folder/file names). But thanks a lot for the recommendation, as a new R enthusiast I wasn't aware of that simple command which shows you the number of files if you specify a path. Cheers!